# Debugging pgf-math

Tags: tikz-pgf

Just learned about pgfmath, but how can I debug it?

```
\pgfmathparse{..} \pgfmathresult
```

doesn't print anything inside a tikzpicture environment. How can I simply print the result of an expression to check weather the calculation was done correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Christoph mentioned this but it's worth making explicit.  If you don't want to actually draw anything you don't need a `tikzpicture` environment and you don't need to put `\pgfmathresult` in nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathparse{2+3}
\pgfmathresult
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to "just print out the result", you don't need to use pgfmath inside a tikzpicture. If you want to place the result in a picture, put it into a node:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 2 + 3 = \pgfmathparse{2+3}\pgfmathresult\\
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0,0) {2 + 2 = \pgfmathparse{2+2}\pgfmathresult};
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note: Calculating the value before placing the node will not work, because the placing the node will overwrite the old result.

Comment: NO EASIER WAY?!

Comment: You will need to tell tikz where to place your result. If in doubt, your node will be placed at the current point, so you can omit the `at (x,y)` part. If your're currently constructing a path, you can get away with `node {\pgfmathparse{...}\pgfmathresult}`, so all you have to add is `node {}`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to launch pgf completely

```
\documentclass{article} 
\input{pgfutil-common.tex}
\usepackage{pgfkeys,pgfmath}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathparse{2+3*2}
\pgfmathresult
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for finding the minimal set of packages.  I started with `pgfmath`, then found I needed `pgfkeys`, but then got funny errors that I couldn't diagnose.  So I just went with `pgf`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do the math in `tikzpicture`, you can also use `\show\pgfmathresult` to display the result in the console.